# Drawing n intervals uniformly randomly, probability that at least one interval overlaps with all others

Tags: probability

Randomly draw $n$ intervals from $[0,1]$, where each end point are selected from from the uniform distribution between $[0,1]$.

What's the probability that at least one interval overlaps with all others?

Comment: Should "one" be replaced with "at least one" or "exactly one" or "a particular"? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer thanks, it should be at least one.

Comment: A solution is given at the end of this document: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135A/resources/chpr.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1<\dots<x_{2n}$ be the $2n$ points sampled, after sorting them in increasing order (all points are different with probability 1). When are the corresponding intervals all disjoint? Only when $x_1,x_2$ belong to one interval, $x_3,x_4$ to another, and so on. Since all permutations are equally likely, the probability that *no two intervals overlap* is
$$
\frac{2^n n!}{(2n!)}.
$$
For small $n$ starting with $1$, these probabilities are
$$
1, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{15}, \frac{1}{105}, \frac{1}{945}, \ldots.
$$
The reciprocal sequence has many combinatorial interpretations, see [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147) on the OEIS.

The probability you are after can be calculated along the same lines. Surprisingly, it turns out to be always $2/3$.

Comment: The complement of the event "no two intervals overlap" is "some two intervals overlap," not "some interval overlaps all others."

Comment: @Sameer Yes, I just realized that. But the same method would work.

Comment: Trying numbers, I immediately get that $\: n=0 \:$ and $\: n=1 \:$ are counterexamples to your claim that the probability the OP is asking about "turns out to be always 2/3." $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Fortunately, these numbers are the only counterexamples.